# idea.find() function is not working in for loop

Tags: express

When I am trying to retrieve values from Array using for loop values are retrieved but `idea.find({ideaid:ideaid},function(err,ideaid){});` in this function, only one value has been taking so how can find all ids of idea

```
    app.get('/getideabyevent',function(req,res,next){
    var eventId = req.param('eventid');
    var IDS = null;
    scores.find({eventid:eventId},function(err,eideas){
        for(let i=0;i<eideas.length;++i){
            IDS = eideas[i].ideaid;
            idea.find({_id:IDS},function(err,ideas){
                if(IDS.length==ideas.length){
                res.json({ideas});  
                }else{
                next()  
                }

            if(err){
            res.json({err});    
            }
            else{
            res.json({ideas});
            console.log(ideas);     
            }

        }); 
            console.log(IDS);
        }

    });
});
```

`console.log(IDS);` showing array all elements but find function have taking one element. Could you please give me the suggestion for solve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Your sample code doesn't show where "idea" came from.

Comment: which is from ideaschema actually i have assigned ideaschema with idea variable like var idea = require('config/ideaschema');